# Expand arguments passed to bash function that contains quotes

Tags: bash

I want to execute this curl command with the json body. I want to able to execute it with the help of a bash function such as 'query_db myId myClass'

```
function query_db(){
    curl -x socks5h://localhost:30001 -X POST https://my-db.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/my_db/_search?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": [
        { "match": { "eventData.clazz":   "'$2'"       }},
        { "match": { "eventData.itemId":   "'$1'"       }}
      ]
  }
}
}'
}
```

However, the above query fails because $2 and $1 is not expanded into the actual arguments. How do I fix this function?

Comment: They should be expanded, but the way they're quoted (/not quoted) is very fragile, and will fail if either of them contains any whitespace or JSON metacharacters (or possibly some other shell metacharacters). Put the `set -x` command before the problem section of the script to make it print an execution trace of what's actually happening (and `set +x` after it, to turn off tracing). But really, you should be using `jq` or something similar to create valid JSON (as in chepner's answer).

Answer (score 1):

Use `jq` to ensure that your strings are incorporated, correctly quoted, into a JSON object.

```
# Lots of unnecessary whitespace for readability.
json_template='
  {
    query: {
      bool: {
        must: [
           {
             match: {
               "eventData.clazz": $x
             }
           },
           {
             match: {
               "eventData.itemId": $y
             }
           }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
'

query_db(){
  jq -n --arg x "$2" --arg y "$1" "$json_template" |
    curl -x socks5h://localhost:30001 \
         -X POST \
         -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
         -d @- \
         "https://my-db.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/my_db/_search?pretty"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything within a single quote is interpreted literally in shell. Try removing the single quote or escaping it if you need to include it.