# Bash script for creating multiple projects in harbor

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I wanted to create multiple projects in harbor with the API. so i have 5 projects to create in the text file

projects.txt

```
projects: abcd
          efgh
          ijkl
          mnop
          qrst
```

create_projects.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=$( cd "$( dirname "$BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )


while read p 
do
    curl --location --request POST 'https://harbor.rl.com/api/v2.0/projects' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'X-Resource-Name-In-Location: true' --header 'Authorization: Basic jhgkyyktfkghfgfhfgh=' --data-raw '{ 
"project_name": $p,
"public": true,
"metadata": { 
"public": "true", 
"prevent_vul": "true",
"auto_scan": "true"
},
"storage_limit": -1 
}'
done < "$DIR/../assets/projects.txt"
```

i created bash script like this. please suggest how we gonna create these five projects in the harbor repo through the script

Comment: The shell doesn't expand variables inside single-quotes. In any case, you shouldn't interpolate raw data into JSON. Use something like `jq` that'll format it properly. See [chepner's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68778042/expand-arguments-passed-to-bash-function-that-contains-quotes/68778202#68778202).

Comment: Thanks Gordan, actually i am new to this scripting. is there any other way to write script for creating  projects in the harbor. i am not understanding with jq how it is creating.

Comment: Is there any option to create ansible playbook for the above requirement